# Initialize array of objects in constructor

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, constructor

I wrote a class that holds an array of objects, which each expect a pointer to a c-struct in their constructor:

Here's some code:

```
 class TheOtherClass
   {
     private: 
       SomeCStruct* m_pCStruct;
       int m_ObjIdx;

     public:
         TheOtherClass::TheOtherClass(SomeCStruct* pCStruct, int ClassIdx)
            : m_pCStruct(pCStruct),
              m_ObjIdx(ClassIdx)
         {}
     }

   class MyClass
    {
     private:
         TheOtherClass m_objects[4];
         SomeCStruct* m_pMyCStruct;

     public:
         MyClass::MyClass(SomeCStruct* pCStruct)
             : m_pMyCStruct(pCStruct)
         {
             m_objects[4] = {TheOtherClass(&pCStruct, 1), TheOtherClass(&pCStruct, 2), 
                             TheOtherClass(&pCStruct,3), TheOtherClass(&pCStruct, 4)};
         }
```

I'd actually like to initialize the member objects of MyClass in the init list of the constructor but I was reading this isn't possible?
Hence I tried the above approach but I'm always getting the error: "TheOtherClass": no appropriate default constructor available.

Another thing to mention is that the compiler I'm running is a state of the art C++03 compiler ;-) (it's code for a DSP and TI sort of doesn't wants to update the compiler)

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: `private: TheOtherClass m_objects[4];` -- Your error doesn't need all of this code to be duplicated:  `int main() { TheOtherClass t; }` -- Just that alone can't be done, all due to not having a default constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `MyClass(SomeCStruct* pCStruct)` constructor doesn't *(can't)* initialize the `TheOtherClass m_objects` in the member initializer list, the `m_objects` **will need to be default constructed** at first, and then this member will be reassigned with new value **in the body of the `MyClass` constructor**.

The `TheOtherClass` **won't have a synthesized constructor** since **you have defined (other, non-default) ctor** that takes `SomeCStruct*` and `int`. Thus, no default constructor for it in your code.

Here, we define a default constructor:

```
class TheOtherClass {
    SomeCStruct* m_pCStruct;
    int m_ObjIdx;
public:
    TheOtherClass() : m_pCStruct(nullptr), m_ObjIdx(0) {} // Default ctor
    TheOtherClass(SomeCStruct* pCStruct, int ClassIdx)
            : m_pCStruct(pCStruct),
              m_ObjIdx(ClassIdx) {}
};
```

As to the `MyClass`. Since you've already pass the argument as a pointer `MyClass(SomeCStruct* pCStruct)`, you don't need to take the address of it (as in `&pCStruct`).

And the main issue in the `MyClass` is that the `m_objects` is of class type `TheOtherClass` which does not define any `operator=`, including the one that takes brace-enclosed initializer list. So, you won't be able to do like so:

```
m_objects[4] = { // The operator '=' has not been defined for the TheOtherClass, also note the subscript
    TheOtherClass(pCStruct, 1),
    TheOtherClass(pCStruct, 2), 
    TheOtherClass(pCStruct,3),
    TheOtherClass(pCStruct, 4)
};
```

Again, when you try to list initialize it, it has already been default constructed. Thus, for this approach to work you will need to define such **copy-assignment operator** to do this kind of assignment to an already default constructed instance of the `TheOtherClass`. As to how to implement this operator, it will mostly depend on the overall design and other factors which were not mentioned in this thread.

#### Update

If you will have the following body of the `MyClass` constructor, it will work:

```
MyClass(SomeCStruct* pCStruct) : m_pMyCStruct(pCStruct) {
    // Assign to default initialized TheOtherClass object
    m_objects[0] = TheOtherClass(pCStruct, 1); 
}
```

I would advise you to check these:

[Operator overloading](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators)

[Constructors and member initializer lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor)

Comment: @KarlPoarf you may want to consider using a standard library container, which suits the most instead of an variable length array.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time for the detailed answer.
The & operator of course is wrong in that example. Call it a copy / paste error ;) 
I added a default constructor and it does seem to work if I know initialize every member of the array by itself. So init in the body of the constructor of MyClass looks like this now:

`m_objects[0] = TheOtherClass(&pCStruct, 1); `

Comment: I guess you mean something like vector? I need to dive into the embedded std lib for that a little bit but it might be worth the try .... for several reasons

Comment: @KarlPoarf the convenience of use will definitely worth researching.

Comment: Jap that works. Hopefully no suprises pop up when I test this :P 
I'll check those links. I'm obviously having a big lack of understanding regarding this subject.

Comment: @KarlPoarf I'm sure this lack of understanding is temporary. Best of luck!

Comment: just another question regarding the default constructor or how `TheOtherClass` actually gets initialized. Imagine m_ObjIdx would be const, so: `const int m_ObjIdx`. Would the above still work? I mean if it's const, how could it be overwritten by another initialization or does this overwrite never really happen?

Comment: @KarlPoarf this should be extensively covered in the documentation, but here's the [excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16168742/14624729). In short, no. In such case it won't work.

Comment: Jep I thought so. But I can't imagine that there is no way to do what I am trying to do.  I would really like to make sure that m_ObjIdx never changes after the class gets initialized.

Comment: @KarlPoarf then make (leave) it private, and do not provide a way for any public method to change it, then you're safe. If you need to read it out, provide a `const` *"getter"* method.

Comment: fair enough. Thanks for the tips. Really appreciate you're taking the time to help us noobs out ;)